# What is the best way to store HTML elements with BeautifulSoup for later use?

Tags: javascript, python, html, xpath, beautifulsoup

My aim is to use BeautifulSoup, extract certain HTML elements (in this case those containing alphabets), store them and later identify them on the original website with javascript (for eg. with document.getElementsbyClassName...)

I am extracting HTML elements with the following Python code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re 

def parse_html(html): 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    
    text_only = []

    for elem in soup(text= re.compile('[A-Za-z]+')) :
            text_only.append(elem)
            
    return text_only
```

I then store this in a DB. My use case is that I would want to later use these to identify that particular element on the original website. But I am not sure how do I do this? I used [this](https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf) code to generate the Xpath, store and then use it on the original website with this JS code:

```js
let parse = document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[3]/a", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

However, this returns undefined. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the HTML content in json or txt provided the HTML content should be string. I have saved in txt format. Try this out and see if you are meeting your expectation or not.

```
URL = 'some_url'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#open and write the file (html should be stored in string format)
file_open = open("html_file.txt", "w")
file_open.write(str(soup))
file_open.close()

#open and read file
file_open = open("html_file.txt", "r")
file_read = file_open.read()
file_open.close()

#reuse saved HTML code
reuse_html = BeautifulSoup(file_read, 'html.parser')
print(reuse_html)
```